# Splitting field as a terminal object?

Tags: category-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ be a polynomial over field $K$ and let $E$ be a splitting field. I would like to prove that $E$ is unique up to isomorphism by expressing the inclusion $K\to E$ as a terminal object in some category (i.e., I would like to write down the universal property of splitting fields in categorical language).

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Why would you expect $K\to E$ to be a **terminal** object? $E$ is (morally) the smallest extension of $K$ in which $f$ splits, so I'd expect $K \to E$ to be an **initial** object in the category of extensions $K \to F$ in which $f$ splits. This doesn't work because $E$ has isomorphisms that fix $K$, but I expect you can fix that by identifying morphisms that just permute the roots of $f$.

Comment: @Rob: I think the idea is to make $E$ the largest field you can make by adjoining roots.

Comment: Why has this got 4 upvotes?

Comment: @RobArthan I was using "terminal" in the sense of Paolo Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0". He uses "terminal" to mean either "initial" or "final".

Comment: @DrewArmstrong: thanks for the explanation. It makes sense with that clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. The reason is that the splitting field is not unique up to *unique* isomorphism, and any terminal object has to be unique in this stronger sense.

Comment: Nice, and by the way, you are one of my GSIs for Math 54.